# Pass data to html table with socket io

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, socket.io

I have consume data from API and that data will be displayed real time in a table using socketio, where it has a data return in the form of an object, like this the examples :

```
"data": [
    {
      "name": "e7876319e4",
      "status_waiter": "Ready"
    },
    {
      "name": "e787631334",
      "status_waiter": "Ready"
    }
]
```

so I want to display that data in an HTML table, where if there is a change in the data the table must also change, and there I do the interval settings, then how do I do it?

I was tried use `$('#status').append(data)` that is a success but it keeps the data adding even though there are no changes.

Comment: did you try ```$('#status').html(data)```?

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
$('#status').empty(); //removes existing
$('#status').append(data); //add new
```

AS:

```
function updateTable(){
    let data = []; // set data here
    $('#status').empty(); //removes existing
    $('#status').append(data); //add new

    setTimeout(()=>{updateTable();}, 1000); //call this after 1 second
}

// call this when ever you want to start the updatefor the first time, after that...
updateTable();
```